# Asymptotic estimate for a special sum

Tags: summation, logarithms, asymptotics

I seek the asymptotic behavior for the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil \frac{\log n}{1/2\log\log n} \rceil}\sqrt{\log(n/(\log n)^{i/2})}$$

Is there a better (and still simple) estimate than $O\left(\frac{\log^{3/2}n}{\log \log n}\right)$?

Comment: Are you sure that you want the ceiling, rather than the floor in that upper limit? Once $i$ gets above that expression, the log in the sqrt will be negative.

Comment: Yes, that was the floor. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around to see what happens.

$S(n)
=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{\log n}{1/2\log\log n} \rfloor}\sqrt{\log(n/(\log n)^{i/2})}
$.

Note that floor is needed in the upper limit,
otherwise the log can go negative.

$f(n) =\log(n/(\log n)^{i/2})
=\log(n)-(i/2)\log\log(n)
$.

Let
$a = \frac{\log n}{1/2\log\log n}
$
and
$b = \lfloor a \rfloor 
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{f(n)}
&= \sqrt{\log(n)-(i/2)\log\log(n)}\\
&= \sqrt{\log(n)}\sqrt{1-(i/2)\log\log(n)/\log(n)}\\
&= \sqrt{\log(n)}\sqrt{1-i/a}\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
S(n)
&=\sqrt{\log(n)}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor a\rfloor}\sqrt{1-i/a}\\
&=\sqrt{\log(n)}a\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor a\rfloor}\frac1{a}\sqrt{1-i/a}\\
&\approx\sqrt{\log(n)}a\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x}dx\\
&=\sqrt{\log(n)}\dfrac{\log n}{1/2\log\log n}\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}dx\\
&=\dfrac{\log^{3/2} n}{1/2\log\log n}\dfrac{x^{3/2}}{3/2}\big|_0^1\\
&=\dfrac{4\log^{3/2} n}{3\log\log n}\\
\end{array}
$

It looks like
your big-oh estimate
is correct,
so nothing better
can be done.